# member is inaccessible C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am new to C++.While working with class and object I tried this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class patient {

string name;
int age;
int room;
};
int main()
{
patient me;
me.name = "Zuahir";
me.age = 16;
me.room = 365;
cout << me.name;

return 0;
}
```

But this gives me a `member inaccessible` error.
Kindly help me in this case

Comment: It looks like you would beneift from one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Learning by guessing is very inefficient, and C++ is almost entirely dissimilar to Python.

Comment: I am good at python, just learning c++ for competetive programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ default access modifier for a `class` is private.

Please use public access modifier before class attributes.

Like:

```
class patient {
  public:
   string name;
   int age;
   int room;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`class`-members are private by default in c++. If you want to acces them directly, make them public:

```
class patient {
  public:
    string name;
    int age = 0;//<-- don't leave those int's uninitialized ;)
    int room = 0;
};
```

Or declare it as a `struct`:

```
struct patient {
    string name;
    int age = 0;
    int room = 0;
};
```

Comment: your wording suggests that a struct is not a class, but a class declared with the keyword `struct` is also a class. Really the only difference is default access

Comment: @idclev463035818 Right you are, changed my wording accordingly

Comment: `std::string` is not POD, and any `struct` or `class` that contains a non-POD type is also non-POD.    In any event, a `struct` and a `class` are identical in C++, except for default access and inheritance being `public` rather than `private`.  It is equally correct to describe a `struct` as a `class` with different default access, as it is to describe a `class` as a `struct` with different default access.

Comment: @Eljay, Peter Yes, my bad, removed the whole POD part.